# Printing the SQL Query in Django when using a Database Router

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am using Django 1.8 and Python 2.7. I would like to use a database other than the 'default' one for which we can have blank parameters as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/). Let's call that database 'test'. In order to make django work I need to do some sort of routing. For now, I just route everything to the 'test' db like so:

```
class Router(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Reads go to a randomly-chosen replica.
        """
        return 'test'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Writes always go to primary.
        """
        return 'test'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are
        in the primary/replica pool.
        """
        return True

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):
        """
        All non-auth models end up in this pool.
        """
        return True


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['test123.settings.Router']
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'test': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I make a simple model (taken from the Django tutorial):

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

I now make/run the appropriate migrations. I can make queries such as `Question.objects.all()` in shell, which returns `[]`. However, now when I call `print Question.objects.all().query`, it gives an error saying `settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value.` I think it is using the 'default' database instead of the 'test' database. Is there a way to fix this so I can see the raw SQL query?

Comment: In `allow_migrate`, instead of returning `True`, I think you should have `return db == 'test'`

Comment: @RohitJain the docs state that allow_migrate does the following:    Determine if the migration operation is allowed to run on the database with alias db. Return True if the operation should run, False if it shouldn’t run, or None if the router has no opinion. Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: Yeah, but if you return `True` always, it will try migration on `default` db too. Which is wrong I guess.

Comment: Hmm I should probably change that, but I don't think it matters for my question because I was able to make/apply the migrations on the correct db. I know this because I was able to make some basic queries such as `Question.objects.all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Model.objects.using('test').all().query`.

You can manually select a database with `using`. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset).

**Update**:

Provide just the `ENGINE` value for `DATABSES['default']`

Django raises an `ImproperlyConfigured` exception on every api function when the `default` database `ENGINE` is empty. See the docstring [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/53ccffdb8c8e47a4d4304df453d8c79a9be295ab/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py).

Comment: I get the same error when using this command and switching the position of the using statement makes no difference.

Comment: Maybe if you provide just the ENGINE value for 'default'? Set it to sqlite3 as well.

Comment: That seems to have worked even without the `using` command. Is there any reason you know why you need that? The docs seem to indicate that you don't need to do so.

Comment: If it is as you said, why do the documents give an example of just a blank parameters.

Comment: `Django requires that a default database entry be defined, but the parameters dictionary can be left blank if it will not be used. ` from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: Good question. My guess is that Django still selects the 'default' database for outputting the query. Validating this would require some debugging/stepping through Django code to see which db is selected.